# Delete logs in loki

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

is there any way to delete logs from Loki without table manager config like this:

```
table_manager:
  retention_deletes_enabled: true
  retention_period: 336h
```

This way is too destructive and not very useful, so I was wondering is there any better way to do it, for example by label or something?

Answer (score 0):

Now, in master branch, the feature has been developed, but it's not in latest release (tag v2.2.1). so wait a moment.

**master**

- https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/pkg/storage/stores/shipper/compactor/compactor.go#L39
- https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/main/pkg/loki/modules.go#L620

**2.2.1**

- https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/v2.2.1/pkg/storage/stores/shipper/compactor/compactor.go#L27
- https://github.com/grafana/loki/blob/v2.2.1/pkg/loki/modules.go#L570